# Calculate the determinant of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-calculus

I f
$$A_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}= \begin{pmatrix}x_{1}^{n}& x_{1}^{n-1} &\ldots& x_{1}& 1 \\ 
x_{2}^{n}& x_{2}^{n-1} &\ldots& x_{2}& 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots \\
x_{n}^{n}& x_{n}^{n-1} &\ldots& x_{n}& 1 \\
1&1&\ldots&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
be a matrix, i like to calculate the $det (A)$. I think that this matrix is rather than like vandrmonde matrix, what is your idea?

Comment: i think $det(A)$ is a product of $(x-x_{i})$ 's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\det(A)$ will be a degree ${n+1}\choose 2$ polynomial in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  (**Why?**)

Now observe that for $i\ne j$, if $x_i=x_j$ then $\det(A)=0$ by properties of the determinant.  Therefore, $(x_i-x_j)$ is a factor of that polynomial for each $i\ne j$.

Furthermore, if $x_i=1$ for any $i$ then $\det(A)=0$.  So $(x_i-1)$ is a factor of $\det(A)$ for each $i$.

Putting all this together, we see that $\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)\prod_{j<i}(x_i-x_j)$ is a factor of $\det(A)$.  But what is the degree of that polynomial?  And what does that tell us?

Answer (score 0):

Classic [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) has rows of elements in geometric progression, starting from 1.

You can transform this matrix in a Vandermonde one by multiplying each row $i$ by $x_i^{-n}$, so that the row becomes 
$$
1\quad \left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\quad \left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^2\quad \left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^3\cdots\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^n
$$

The formula should follow easily. When you compute the determinant with the Vandermonde formula, remember that you have scaled the matrix.

EDIT, yeah, do like Donkey_2009 says.

Comment: There's no need to multiply by $x_i^{-n}$; just swapping the rows and columns so the $1$s appear at the left hand side will put it into that form.